# Using Vertex Arrays in Qt

Tags: arrays, qt, opengl, vertex

After messing around with the Qt-way of implementing VBOs, I wanted to use regular vertex arrays in my paintGL() method.
However, it seems certain commands are not supported by QOpenGLWidget / QOpenGLFunctions:

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &currentSkeleton);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 38, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &skeletonIndices);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Compiling throws 3 x error LNK2019, unresolved extern symbol:

```
... "__imp__glDisableClientState@4" ...
...  "__imp__glVertexPointer@16"    ...
... "__imp__glEnableClientState@4" ...
fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I've already tried including the likes of

```
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Compatibility>
```

Is there something I'm missing? 
I can use *glBindTexture* and *glTexImage2D* without any problem...

Answer (score -2):

> the Qt-way of implementing VBOs*

Once and foerever: ***there is no such thing***.

**Vertex Buffer Objects are an OpenGL concept.**

Qt does *not* care about them, at all.

<sub>(Yes, there's a Qt class to help you manage VBOs, but the keyword here is *help* -- if you want to do things yourself, you can.)</sub>

---

That having been said, you should carefully read the documentation about using OpenGL on Windows (hint: it's a nightmare), and the workarounds that Qt needs to put in place in order to deliver OpenGL:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers

The short story is that Qt does not link against `opengl32.lib`, so if you want to use OpenGL functions like that, you need to link against it in your own project by adding

```
LIBS += opengl32.lib
```

to your `.pro` file.

Possibly, you need to tell Qt that you're doing that, so you should also set the `Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL` application attribute. Read those docs, I can't just copy and paste all the explaination in here. :)

And finally, fixed pipeline GL code in 2015? Seriously?

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer; I'm still in both areas, OpenGL as a whole and Qt itself. I should've tackled one thing at a time probably, but I have crossed the point of no return already. ;) The problem is, there are so many tuts/docs out there that are deprecated, but are not obviously marked as such, and everything is quite confusing, so I got myself a relatively new book about OpenGL will carry on from there.